# How to install gitpython with, Failed to initialize: Bad git executable

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, gitpython

I am trying to install git-python on *Windows*. I tried to install it using the git command:

```
pip install gitpython
```

It installed just fine and it install in my local app data. The only problem was is when I ran it, it gave me this error:

Failed to initialize: Bad git executable.
The git executable must be specified in one of the following ways:

- be included in your $PATH
- be set via $GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE
- explicitly set via git.refresh()

In addition I ran pip install gitpython:

Requirement already satisfied: gitpython in c:\users\morga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (3.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: gitdb<5,>=4.0.1 in c:\users\morga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from gitpython) (4.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: smmap<4,>=3.0.1 in c:\users\morga\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from gitdb<5,>=4.0.1->gitpython) (3.0.4)

I do not have it the folder of git. I only found anything remotely to git was in my appdata local

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As in [issue 816](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/816), check your `GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE` environment variable:

```
C:\>:: This does NOT work
C:\>set GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE="C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe"
C:\>%GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE% --version
git version 2.20.1.windows.1

C:\>:: This does work
C:\>set GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE=C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

Replace `C:\Program Files\Git\` by your own Git installation folder (using, as [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62856409/how-to-install-gitpython-with-failed-to-initialize-bad-git-executable/62856518?noredirect=1#comment118579046_62856518) by [Jeromy Adofo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1642557/jeromy-adofo), `where git`).
If you don't have Git installed, you can installed the latest [Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).

Comment: %GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE% --version
The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: @Cyber_Pig_908 Yes, that is expected. Does it work in gitpython though?

Comment: I am sorry. I do not understand. Do I run it and cmd as admin?

Comment: No, regular account only

Comment: It still did not work. I don't if this helps but I don't have git in program files. I just have it in Appdata local

Comment: @Cyber_Pig_908 I agree: my answer was using that path as an example: you should replace it with your path to your Git.

Comment: @Cyber_Pig_908 Have you installed (or re-installed) your Git For Windows? I realized `import git` in an interactive python shell was failing with the same error as yours. However after installing Git For Windows, it now works.

Comment: As a side note, you can find the location of your git executable by running `where git` in Command Prompt (cmd)

Comment: @JeromyAdofo Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.